# Как получить ключ доступа сообщества VK API?

Tags: vkontakte-api, android-vksdk

Работаю в Android Studio.
С получением ключа доступа (токена) для пользователя проблем нет.

Использую:

```
VKSdk.login(this, scope);
```

А как быть с ключом сообщества?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все очень просто. Заходите в `управление сообществом`, ищите раздел `работа с API`, там кликаете `создать ключ`, далее разберетесь)